# Oath2 open Id connect - How to exchange access_token for a id_token

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

I am using Forgerock as my identity provider and am looking for something in their rest api where i can provide an access token in the form of a Authorisation Bearer Token and get the corresponding JWT token to use as a Authorisation Bearer Token in a subsequent rest api call.

Can someone help me with what endpoint I can call in Forgerock to do this? I've had a look at the userinfo endpoint, that seems to return what is in the id_token in json format, but I want the actual id_token. A "token exchange".

thanks

Comment: one cannot swap an access_token for an id_token without explicit user interaction as dictated by the spec that defines an id_token (OpenID Connect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no endpoint defined by specifications to obtain and ID token for an access token. Specificaitons define about token intrsopection endpoint ([RFC7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)) and user info endpoint (which you have already figured out).

Other than these, best option is to obtain ID Token from token response itself. For this you need to follow OpenID Connect request format, which include scope value `openid`. For this, you will require end use consent (most of the time) which allows authorization server to share their claims through id token.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeconfig)  says that you can specify response_type for `gapi?.auth.authorize`

You can use it to get id_token